# switch between multiple version of cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have Xcode 7.3.1 and Xcode 8 and using both of them for two different projects. Each project needs a different version of cocoapods. So I have to have two cocoapods versions installed.
How can I switch between the two versions ? In other words when I use Xcode 7 I need a version and when I use Xcode 8 I need the other version of cocoapods.

Thanks

Comment: just make another branch or tag for it and clone the correct branch?

Comment: did my answer help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pod --version
```

lists all the version of coco pods in your system

```
pod _1.0.1_ install  #uses 1.0.1 version
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. But what if I have the two versions already installed and I want to select the one I need, should I run the same command again ?

Comment: @Sam did you find any solution for this?

Comment: If two pod version are there i think there is no other solution other than the above method .